# Why MobaXterm tellnet session in remote session enter key displays ^M instead of regular new line?

Tags: mobaxterm

Throught windows remote session MobaXterm tellnet session print ^M instead of new line when enter key in pressed.
Is there a way to have regular new line when pressing enter without ^M?

Comment: Workaround is to configure in Advanced telnet settings of the session : Telnet client : "Busybox telnet".

Answer (score 1):

In mobaXtem, if you use the default 'PuTTY' telnet client - new line can be typed using
Ctrl-Enter